# how to translate virtual address to a physical?

Tags: memory, virtual-memory

I need to convert a virtual address into a physical. My boss gave me [this](https://shanetully.com/2014/12/translating-virtual-addresses-to-physcial-addresses-in-user-space/) article but at the end of the article is says the following:

> It’s is not intended to be behavior that should be relied upon. In
>   fact, in my testing, I experiened the kernel shuffling around physical
>   addresses between the time at which I calculated the offset to seek to
>   and writing data to that offset. The bottom line is: stick to virtual
>   memory; it works really well.

Does anyone know how to do it in a different way?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please tell me why you need to do this?

Comment: @EdHeal I'm working on an application that needs to talk to a device which will uses shared memory for communication. The addresses for shared memory must be physical. This is a temporary solution until a driver is developed.

Comment: What OS? Is it is of UNIX flavor then you can gain access to shared memory using a key

Comment: @EdHeal It is Linux. I've never worked on this type of software before. So any details would be highly appreciated. What do you mean by a key?

Comment: This example might help - http://www.cse.psu.edu/~deh25/cmpsc473/notes/OSC/Processes/shm.html

Comment: @EdHeal This is a good link but I don't think this is what I'm looking for. Here is what I found from them `man mmap`: `mmap() creates a new mapping in the virtual address space of the calling process. `. Let me give you a more details. I need to create a buffer and I need a for a device to read this buffer. If I give a buffer address to this device it will be an incorrect one as it is a virtual address. How do I convert a virtual buffer address to a physical buffer address?

Comment: You need kernel mode access to do this. Plus, in most cases, the logical address to physical address mapping can change.

Comment: @user3344003 So even while the process is running the mapping can change? My expectation was that while the process is running, the mapping stays the same. Is my expectation wrong?

Comment: That is wrong, unless you are dealing with something that that operating system determines has a fixed address (e.g., device registers, video memory).

Comment: In fact, at any given point in time, a virtual address may have no physical address at all.

Comment: @user3344003 Let's take a concrete example. A device needs to read/write from a host memory (regular RAM). A device is memory mapped. If it needs to read/write anything it generates a physical address for an operation. Say I have a regular C program with a character buffer, `char buf[256].` Is it possible for this device to read/write this buffer without using a driver? If it isn't then how would a driver do it? I still have to convert between physical and virtual addresses in both directions, i.e. physical->virtual and virtual->physical in the driver.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114975/discussion-between-flashburn-and-user3344003).